# Export function as "root" of module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When writing a TypeScript definition, how do you declare that the definition defines a function, rather than a type? So that the function is exported as the module itself...

**Definition**

```
declare module "rmdir" {
    interface IRmDirCallback {
        (err: any, dirs: Array<string>, files: Array<string>): any;
    }

    function rmdir(dir: string, options: any, callback: IRmDirCallback): void;

    export = rmdir;
}

export = rmdir.rmdir;
```

**Usage Example**

```
/// <reference path="rmdir.d.ts"/>

import rmdir = require("rmdir");

rmdir("test", { }, (err: any, dirs: Array<string>, files: Array<string>) => { });
```

So when I import `rmdir`, I dont' want to have to call `rmdir.rmdir(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `export =`. Here is the complete code:

```
declare module "rmdir" {
    function rmdir(dir: string, options: any, callback: (err: any, dirs: Array<string>, files: Array<string>) => any): void;
    export = rmdir;
}
```

Comment: This was promising, but I can't seem to load the module. Upon running, I get the error message "Cannot find module 'rmdir'". My assumption is that this is because I've exported a function. not a module! Updated the OP with current code, please take a look if you have a minute.

Comment: ` Upon running, I get the error message "Cannot find module 'rmdir'"` Make sure you have it installed. This not specific to TypeScript. Just NodeJS ecosystem. TIP: `npm install rmdir --save`